# Sorting colors by the name of the color

Tags: java, performance, sorting, javafx

I was in need to sort `Color`s, so the first thing that I tried was this:

```
Arrays.sort(new javafx.scene.paint.Color[] {Color.ALICEBLUE},Color.AZURE,Color.BLUEVIOLET,Color.AQUA,...);
```

But unfortunately `Arrays.Sort` is not compatible with [`javafx.scene.paint.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html), so I ended up with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] colors = {"AQUA", "LAWNGREEN", "LIGHTBLUE", "CYAN", "CHOCOLATE", "GREEN",
        "RED", "YELLOW", "GAINSBORO", "YELLOWGREEN"};

    final Function<String, ? extends Color> valueMapper = (final String name) -> {
        try {
            return (Color) Color.class.getField(name).get(null);
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
    final Map<String, Color> map = Arrays.stream(colors).collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), valueMapper));

    map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey)).forEach((Entry<String, Color> entry) -> {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    });

}
```

Now let me know if this code can be improved and optimized.

Comment: `Arrays` has [`sort(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) and [`sort(T[], Comparator<? extends T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). Your attempt shows you creating an array with 1 element, then a bunch of colors, as if `sort` was `sort(T[], T...)` or `sort(T[], T, T, T)`. Notice your `Color[] { Color.ALICEBLUE }, Color.AZURE, Color.BLUEVIOLET, Color.AQUA`, when it should be `Color[] { Color.ALICEBLUE, Color.AZURE, Color.BLUEVIOLET, Color.AQUA }`

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you're doing here. Are you sorting by colour (i.e. physical colour) or name, or something entirely different?

Answer (score 2):

I like your approach with mapping function, but sorting alphabetically the collection of javafx.scene.paint.Color objects can be done a little bit easier:

```
    final String[] colors = {"AQUA", "LAWNGREEN", "LIGHTBLUE", "CYAN", "CHOCOLATE", "GREEN",
            "RED", "YELLOW", "GAINSBORO", "YELLOWGREEN"};

    Stream.of(colors).sorted().map(color -> Color.web(color)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

as you can see the algorithm quite simple:

1. Sort the string array
2. Map string to Color object using API method